# PHP: Filter some html attributes using preg_replace. Get the first </span>, not the last

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I'm trying to filter an `HTML` file to remove some attributes. Specifically, I want to remove ALL `spans` except the ones that set a color. In the spans that set a color I will remove all the attributes except the style='color...'.

I.e., if I have:

```
<span lang=EN-US>This is a </span>
<span id="myspan" style='color:red;text-align:left;'>test</span>
<span lang=EN-US> to remove spans.</span>
```

I want it to be:

```
This is a
<span style='color:red'>test</span>
to remove spans.
```

To do this I'm using `preg_replace`. I created this `regex`:

```
preg_replace(
    '%(<span [^>]*color\:)([a-z]*)(;|\')([^>]*>)(.*)(<\/span>)%s', 
    "<qwerty style='color:$2'>$5</qwerty>", 
$myText);
```

After using this, I remove all spans with `strip_tags` and then I turn all `<qwerty>` to `<span>`.

My problem is that the content between `<span>` and `</span>` (`(.*)` in my `regex`) is getting **all the text until the end**:

```
This is a 
<span style='color:red'>test
to remove spans.</span>
```

I want it to get all the text until it finds the **first** `</span>`, but now it gets all the text until the **last** `</span>`. How can I do this?

Thanks!

Comment: I think you missed some of the best answers on SO http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use ungreedy (U) modifier:

```
preg_replace('%....%sU', .....);
```

Comment: I didn't expect it to be so easy. Thank you! :)